# Codeigniter 3 unable to read cookie from within iframe of the same domain

Tags: php, jquery, cookies, iframe, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter 3, I use the my URL to load inside iframe of the same website. It creates the cookies well. I can see the details of the cookies in my browser as pasted below.
But from inside of same iframe it can not read the cookies:

```
STRID


Name
STRID

Content
MQ%3D%3D

Domain
www.example.com

Path
/

Send for
Secure same-site connections only

Accessible to script
Yes

Created
Monday, June 7, 2021 at 12:36:12 PM

Expires
Tuesday, June 8, 2021 at 12:36:12 PM
```

I am using PHP 7.3.19 (cli) (built: Jul  5 2020 11:47:45) ( ZTS )
Web Server is Apache 2.4x
Browsers I am using are, Safari, Edge, Chrome, Firefox.

Could somebody help with this

Comment: Could you please tell us, what code you are using to retrieve the cookie? Are you using the cookie helper or session library of Codeigniter?
Also you should update your PHP version if possible.

Comment: I am using below code to read it
<?php
  if (isset($_COOKIE['STRID'])
   {
   $string_id = (int) base64_decode($_COOKIE['STRID']);
   }
 ?>

Comment: just to update, my PHP version is PHP 7.3.19 (cli) (built: Jul  5 2020 11:47:45) ( ZTS )